# What is a .jl.gz file? How do I read it into a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataframes.jl

I have a file with extension .jl.gz (ds_dump_00000.jl.gz).

I'm a python user, and I've never used a file of this format. I'm familiar with the pandas data frame.
How do I read this file into a pandas data frame structure & carry on with analysis?

Comment: "jl" can refer to several things. It may be a "json lines" file - one json object per line. The ".gz" usually means gzipped. Use an archive tool to unzip the file and see what it looks like. On linux/mac it would be `gunzip foo.jl.gz` and you'll end up with `foo.jl`. This is different than a zip file that can have multiple embedded files. Its just a single compressed file.

Comment: as mentioned by @tdelaney this could be `json lines`/`ndjson` file. You can try reading it wilh [json lines package](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/json-lines) or [ndjson package](https://pypi.org/project/ndjson/). Of course if it is ndjson/json lines you can always unzip and read/process line by line as JSON